# get multiple nav menus at one time in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking to get an array of menu nav items with one function. It would be great to do something like

```
wp_nav_menu(['first menu','second menu', 'third menu'])
```

but this obviously does not exist. What would be a another way to generate this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question could use some additional detail as well as examples of code you have tried...  I decided to take a stab and here is what I came up with:

Define a custom function to return an array of `wp_nav_menu` items:

```
// functions.php
// PHP 7.4 or higher
function my_nav_menu($menus) {
  return array_map(fn($menu) => wp_nav_menu($menu, ["echo" => false]), $menus);
}
```

Then you can use it like below:

```
$items = my_nav_menu(['first menu','second menu', 'third menu']);
```